# Is there a size limit of StringRequest parameters?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to upload a base64 encoded image and some text to my webserver using Volley StringRequest.

When I directly try to send the base64 string, I get **'Unexpected response code 503'** but when I compress image  then encode it, its working perfectly. The problem is I don't know why am I have to compress my image before sending to server and how much should I compress it or is there any other way to send it without compressing.

**`base64Encode`** function that I called perfectly working:

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return temp;
    }
```

The **`base64Encode`** function does not work / gives a 503 error :

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);    
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return temp;
    }
```

The line I want you to consider is:

`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);`

When I change this compression parameter to 100 its throwing error.

I thought there might be a size limit when making POST REQUEST or there might be a size limit of Volley `StringRequest` or there might be no size limits at all.

<--- UPDATE --->                                                                If the problem is really a size limit, then how do I calculate what the JPEG size will be after compression with `bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)` without actually compressing it? Or how do I know if I can compress my image enough when I use 15 as the compression parameter?

Comment: Generally there are `8Mb` limit for POST and `4kb` limit for GET. you need to check on your server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that this problem might be caused by the Apache limits the set a size of a client’s HTTP request-line (e.g.   ) and the HTTP request header field size. So you will need to increase the default values if the request URL is too large.
Increase the URI length limit in the Apache configuration file (by default it is /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ):

> LimitRequestLine 16380

> LimitRequestFieldSize 16380

Answer (score 1):

I have also face the same issue. So, It depends on a server configuration. They set the limit for the post to get the data

for eg.

**//Max size**

> post_max_size 20M

So, You need to talk with your backend Guy or send the compressed Image.